# PS4: manual IP address / internet connection failed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, playstation

If I connect my PS4 directly into the wall ethernet then it works fine

But I recently bought a Netgear ethernet switch so that I can connect my PS4 via ethernet but also have my wireless router for other devices.

After connecting everything up, my PS4 couldn't obtain an IP address. So I concluded that my PS4 was trying to use the same IP address as another device on my network.

I managed to specify the IP address for my PS4 manually in the connection settings, but now Im getting the following:

- Obtain IP Address: **Successful**
- Internet Connection: **Failed**

I've noticed, when I test my internet connection on my console, that my 'default gateway' is blank... even though I've specified this in the settings?

My ISP has confirmed that there shouldn't be anything restricting my use of a switch, also I've realised I can connect my PS4 via ethernet by connecting it to one of the 'LAN' ports on my router... but the switch doesn't seem to work

Comment: Where does the wall Ethernet connection lead to? Is it going directly to your ISP? It might be restricted to 1 device at a time (with the intention of you connecting only a router).

Comment: Yes I believe it goes directly to my ISP... that's interesting about possible restrictions! Although I'm sure I tested this a few months ago and believe it worked fine at the time

Comment: Network operators can change their internal network configuration whenever they want. It's only one of several possible explanations, of course, but such restrictions on the "WAN" side are not uncommon.

Comment: @user1686 thanks, Ive just spoke to my ISP (see updated answer at the bottom)

Comment: What is the make and model of the switch?

Comment: If this is a smart/managed switch, the issue is likely the WebUI configuration, but if it's a dumb switch and the wall ethernet goes to a LAN port on a router and that port works without the switch, it could be a bad switch if the switch's power LED lights up _(test by connected it to a LAN port on the router with the PS4 plugged into the switch - if the PS4 receives an IP, there's an issue with the configuration of the endpoint device the wall ethernet port is connected to)_. Does the switch's ethernet port's LED light up orange/green when connected to the powered on PS4?

Comment: You might want to check the cable between your switch and the router.